# How to pass parameters from bash to php script?

Tags: php, bash, shell, parameters, parameter-passing

I have done a a bash script which run php script. It works fine without parameters  but when I add parameters (id and url), there are some errors:

```
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf                                                                                        .d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: /var/www/dev/dbinsert/script/automatisation.php?                                                                                        id=1
```

I run php script from the bash like this:

```
php /var/www/dev/dbinsert/script/automatisation.php?id=19&url=http://bkjbezjnkelnkz.com
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Call it as:

```
php /path/to/script/script.php -- 'id=19&url=http://bkjbezjnkelnkz.com'
```

Also, modify your PHP script to use [parse_str()](http://php.net/parse_str):

```
parse_str($argv[1]);
```

If the index `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` isn't set.

---

More advanced handling may need [getopt()](http://php.net/getopt), but [parse_str()](http://php.net/parse_str) is a quick'n'dirty way to get it working.

Comment: How would you pass a directory into the php script?

Comment: @Michael, same way, just read it from the `$argv` array. Also, thread necromancy is bad.

Comment: I'm not sure if I did something wrong, or if the php has changed, but it is unnecessary to use the `--`.  When I use `$argv[1]`, it just reads the `--`.

Answer (score 6):

You can't pass GET query parameters to the PHP command line interface. Either pass the arguments as standard command line arguments and use the [`$argc` and `$argv` globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php) to read them, or (if you must use GET/POST parameters) call the script through curl/wget and pass the parameters that way – assuming you have the script accessible through a local web server.

This is how you can pass arguments to be read by `$argc` and `$argv` (the -- indicates that all subsequent arguments should go to the script and not to the PHP interpreter binary):

`php myfile.php -- argument1 argument2`

Comment: You can pass GET query parameters if you use php-cgi :)
See examples here: https://serverfault.com/questions/187025/how-to-pass-get-variables-to-a-php-script-via-the-command-line

Answer (score 6):

**-- Option 1: php-cgi --**

Use 'php-cgi' in place of 'php' to run your script. This is the simplest way as you won't need to specially modify your php code to work with it:

```
php-cgi -f /my/script/file.php id=19 myvar=xyz
```

**-- Option 2: if you have a web server --**

If the php file is on a web server you can use 'wget' on the command line:

```
wget 'http://localhost/my/script/file.php?id=19&myvar=xyz'
```

OR:

```
wget -q -O - "http://localhost/my/script/file.php?id=19&myvar=xyz"
```

**-- Accessing the variables in php --**

In both option 1 & 2 you access these parameters like this:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$myvar = $_GET["myvar"];
```