# Passing a value from Bash script to PHP

Tags: php, bash, github

In Bash script, I call something like that

```
# !/bin/bash
output=$(curl -L -H "Authorization: token MY_TOKEN" https://MY_GITHUB_ENTERPRISE/api/v3/repos/USER_NAME/REPO/pulls/123/files)
echo $output
```

I receive a string from output. I want to pass this string into php code to use **json_decode** function. What should I do?

I'm going to write code in PHP part like this. Is it ok? Sorry for the numb question because I'm a newbie in both Bash script and PHP

```
#!/usr/bin/php
$json = json_decode($DATA_FROM_CURL, true);
// Some logic in php

// continue with bash script
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo ABC
```

**Note: I have to write all codes in a Bash script file.

**UPDATE 1**
Thank for Felipe Valdes's suggestion, I updated my code like this. However, I got the return

{"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.8/v3"}

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init();
$TOKEN = 'abclaldslsl';

$header = array();
$header[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$header[] = 'Authorization: token'.TOKEN;

// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://MY_GITHUB_ENTERPRISE/api/v3/repos/USER_NAME/REPO/pulls/123/files");

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot an `$` before your `TOKEN` variable.

Your script could look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init();

$host = 'https://MY_GITHUB_ENTERPRISE'; // your host
$path = "/api/v3/repos/USER_NAME/REPO/pulls/123/files"; // your path
$access_token = 'abclaldslsl'; // your access token

// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host . $path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
[
    'Accept: application/json', // inform the server you want a json response
    'Authorization: token '. $access_token, // set the access token
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// check for errors
if(!$response = curl_exec($ch)) 
{
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
}

print_r(json_decode($output, true));
```

You can use the argument vector (`argv`) to set your path and token if you wish:

```
$path = $argv[1] ?? "/api/v3/repos/USER_NAME/REPO/pulls/123/files";
$access_token = $argv[2] ?? 'abclaldslsl';
```

That would allow you do override the default path and access token which would allow to user your command like this:

```
$ myscript.php /api/v3/repos/USER_NAME/REPO/pulls/123/files MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

In order to pass BASH variables from the environment to your PHP process, 
you may use ARGV and ARGC variables from PHP

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

you may also pass values as a bash variable and fetch the data using getenv():

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

in your case, you can also avoid the bash script all together and simply proceed to fetch the curl url contents directly from PHP using something like file_get_contents or the curl_* functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Also, see this similar question:
[How to pass parameters from bash to php script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779576/how-to-pass-parameters-from-bash-to-php-script)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but returns Bad credentials. What's wrong in my code?