# mysql trigger with php script

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have the next mysql trigger:

```
DELIMITER @@

CREATE TRIGGER Test_Insert
BEFORE INSERT ON sat_clientLocation
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
DECLARE result int(10);
SET cmd=CONCAT('/usr/bin/php ', '/var/www/html/poi/insertTest.php' , NEW.idLocation);
SET result = sys_exec(cmd);

END;
@@
DELIMITER ;
```

It's possible to use NEW.idLocation in my php file?
I try some methods, but don't work.

Comment: add some explanation about your query

Comment: $sql ="SELECT txPostCode, id FROM users WHERE id=(SELECT idClient FROM sat_clientLocation where idLocation= NEW.idLocation)";

Comment: It is not correct, i put  idLocation= NEW.idLocation because there i want to use NEW.idLocation

Comment: What do you mean with _"to use NEW.idLocation in my php file"_? Could you add the PHP code you already have?

Comment: "I try some methods, but don't work." what doesnt work? Because `sys_exec` isn't a MySQL's out off the box function i believe there is a plugin for it.. You might need to use `/usr/bin/php -f` instead  -f option stands for file execution.

Comment: I have already installed the plugin. My problem is that i can't take the NEW.idLocation in  my php code.

Comment: @IsabellaPopa, according to your query in comment, you should use `where in`

Comment: It is not working. My querry is now $sql ="SELECT txPostCode, id FROM users WHERE id=(SELECT idClient FROM sat_clientLocation where idLocation='".$_GET['location']."')";

Answer (score 0):

According to that [solution:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779576/how-to-pass-parameters-from-bash-to-php-script)

```
SET cmd=CONCAT('/usr/bin/php ', 
               '/var/www/html/poi/insertTest.php?location=' ,
               NEW.idLocation);
```

That will be passed to your script as [$_GET[]](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)  variable:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['location'];
?>
```

Comment: The php file is not seen by php exec. Why?