# passing variables from php to bash

Tags: php, html, bash

I have a small PHP file which takes input from a webpage and passes those variables over to a bash script, which gets run on the server.
The input from HTML to PHP works fine and so does the bash script when run on its own. If i change the bash script to write to a file instead that also works, so its getting the variables into the command that seems to fail.

PHP

```
<html>
<title> New VPN password</title>
<h1> Your New VPN login details are</h1>
</html>


<?php
$USERNAME = $_POST['USERNAME'];
$PASSWORD = $_POST['PASSWORD'];
$NEWPASS = $_POST['NEWPASS'];

if(empty($USERNAME ) || empty($PASSWORD )) {
echo "<h2>You must fill in all fields</h2>\n" ;
die ("Click Back to start again.");
}
echo "<b>User Name:</b><br><br>";
echo $USERNAME;
echo "<br><br><b>New Password:</b><br><br>";
echo $NEWPASS;
$addr = shell_exec("sudo /var/www/html/chngpass.sh $USERNAME $PASSWORD $NEWPASS 2>&1");
?>

<html>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<script>
function goBack() {
        window.history.back()
}
</script>

<body>

<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

And the Bash Script is

```
PASSWORD=$1
NEWPASS=$2
USERNAME=$3

echo -e "$NEWPASS\n$NEWPASS" | passwd $USERNAME

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "SUCCESS"
fi
```

Comment: It seems wrong that whenever your script will be fixed anyone who will have access to this form will be able to change the root password.

Comment: Adding the Bash shebang at the beginning of your sh file would help? I think that either you do that or run the command using sh.

Comment: @Lou Won;t they still have to enter the root password?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters from bash to php script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779576/how-to-pass-parameters-from-bash-to-php-script)

Comment: point taken but this is only on a test environment, to which only admins have access.

Comment: They only have access at the moment...

Comment: Have you tried var dumping  $addr, to see if the return of the shell script is what you expect it to be? AFAIK sudo will ask for the sudo password of the user that calls the command, and will only continue running the command if the correct password has been given

Comment: @James the password is not validated, it's ran with sudo.

Answer (score 1):

From your PHP script :

```
$addr = shell_exec("sudo /var/www/html/chngpass.sh $USERNAME $PASSWORD $NEWPASS 2>&1");
```

Your are passing your arguments in the following order "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "NEWPASS" And here is your bash script :

```
PASSWORD=$1
NEWPASS=$2
USERNAME=$3

echo -e "$NEWPASS\n$NEWPASS" | passwd $USERNAME

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "SUCCESS"
fi
```

- Argument 1 (USERNAME) gets assigned to PASSWORD.
- Argument 2(PASSWORD) gets assigned to NEWPASS.
- Argument 3 (NEWPASS)  gets assigned to USERNAME.

Fix your bash script :

```
USERNAME=$1
PASSWORD=$2
NEWPASS=$3        

echo -e "$NEWPASS\n$NEWPASS" | passwd $USERNAME

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "SUCCESS"
fi
```

Comment: Yep. Seems variable order. Good catch @lou

Comment: Spotted that myself, thanks for the heads up. Still struggling to pass any of the variables to passwd?

Comment: Does your bash script work when you run it from CLI?

Comment: @LeeEmmery Don't forget that some characters such as spaces and & must be escaped in your variables. Is there any of those in the username or password you are trying to change? Anyway it would be a good idea to escape your variables in your PHP : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.escapeshellcmd.php

Comment: Not using special charcters in any variables. the scripts works if i set it to output to a txt file it then catches what ever is entered in  the html page. but i wont pass the variables to the passwd command. but if i run     (echo -e "$NEWPASS\n$NEWPASS" | passwd $test ) it will change the user test's password fine.

Comment: I tried your bashscript, it works for me whatever if it's from PHP or bash itself.. Have you tried using the `echo user:password | chpasswd` method?